# Чи можна вважати "троянду" більш українською, ніж "розу"?

Tags: синоніми, іменники, росіянізм

Почула якось, що варто віддавати перевагу вживанню іменника **`троянда`** на позначення "королеви квітів", на противагу нібито росіянізму **`роза`**.

Перевірила за СУМ. Є обидва іменники з тотожними значеннями:

> **[ТРОЯ́НДА](http://sum.in.ua/s/trojanda)**, и, жін.
>
> 1. (Rosa, L.). Багаторічна кущова рослина родини розових з великими запашними квітками червоного, рожевого, білого або жовтого кольору і з
>      стеблами, звичайно вкритими колючками. Високими стеблинами рожа
>      червона стоїть, а синенькі паничі кручені круг неї в'ються... он
>      зірочки червоніють, а он троянди кущ... (Борис Грінченко, II, 1963,
>      372); Над доріжками гнулось рясне від цвіту гілля троянд (Анатолій
>      Шиян, Баланда, 1957, 220).
> 2. Квітка цієї рослини. В локонах білів пучок білих троянд, котрий чудово приставав до її чорних брів (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 245);
>      Ох, розкрились троянди червоні, наче рани палкі, восени (Леся
>      Українка, I, 1951, 227); Троянди — білу, кремову й червону — Я зрізав,
>      не без жалю і вагань (Максим Рильський, II, 1960, 224);  * Образно.
>      Кирило стежив творчі процеси, що відбувались на небі.. Валились
>      розкішні храми, розтавали на альпах сніги, і з пишних троянд осипались
>      рожеві платочки (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 212);  * У
>      порівняннях. — Чого ти оце так змарніла? Колись цвіла, як повна
>      троянда, а тепер така стала, як рожа в'яла (Нечуй-Левицький, VII,
>      1966, 192); У Валентина вуха палали великими трояндами, його сьогодні
>      кожен тягав за вуха (Олесь Гончар, IV, 1960, 91);  //  перев. мн.,
>      перен., поет. Рум'янці. На обличчі її розквітають дві троянди (Натан
>      Рибак, Переяславська Рада, 1948, 213);  //  тільки мн., перен. Про
>      благополуччя, щастя, радощі в житті. — Наш, шлях, ласкавий пане,
>      зовсім не встелений трояндами! (Іван Франко, VI, 1951, 206); Він
>      переможно поглядав на Коваліва, а той ніби не бачив тих поглядів,
>      одвертався: радіти ще рано, бо на шляху в ідеї ростуть не тільки
>      троянди, а й колючки (Михайло Чабанівський, Тече вода.., 1961, 76).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 10, 1979. — Стор. 288.
>
> [**РО́ЗА**](http://sum.in.ua/s/roza), и, жін.
>
> 1. Кущова рослина з великими запашними квітками різних кольорів та стеблами, вкритими колючками; троянда. Рози (троянди) є найкращі
>      декоративно-квіткові рослини (Озеленення колгоспного села, 1955, 238);
>      Дівчина заходилася перев'язувати та підчищати рози (Олександр
>      Ільченко, Серце.., 1939, 405).
> 2. Квітка цієї рослини. Омелян перешугнув зненацька через ковані штахети й зірвав у государевім саду тую розу (Олександр Ільченко,
>      Козацькому роду.., 1958, 536).
> 3. Архітектурна прикраса готичних вікон або саме вікно у вигляді кола з лініями, що радіально розходяться від центра.  ▲ Роза вітрів —
>      графічне зображення повторюваності напрямів і величин сили вітру у
>      певній точці земної поверхні за певний час.
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 8, 1977. — Стор. 600.

Щоправда, Практичний словник синонімів української мови С. Караванського обійшов увагою обидва іменники.

А от Етимологічний словник української мови: у 7 т. Київ: Наук. думка, 2006. Т.5, сс. 104, 653, теж не має нічого проти `рози`.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Тож чи можна й надалі обожнювати українські `рози`, без остраху бути звинуваченим у прихильності до росіянізмів?**

Comment: В українській мові зручно, що ми маємо і *розу*, і *троянду*, бо розою ми можемо називати технічні штуки як-от [*роза вітрів*.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2)

Comment: і не тільки технічні. Наприклад, є розарій, але немає трояндарію.

Comment: хіба?..........

Comment: Принаймні, якщо вірити СУМ [розарій](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozarij)

[трояндарій](http://sum.in.ua/s/trojandarij)

Comment: також на [сайті Національного ботанічного саду ім. М.М. Гришка НАН України](http://www.nbg.kiev.ua/collections_expositions/index.php?SECTION_ID=203) послуговуються терміном "розарій" або синонімом "сад троянд", але не трояндарій. НМД, трояндарій почали вживати, щоб уникнути нібито росіянізму.

Comment: А відколи в українській мові є слово розарій? Може це з доби коли в української мови не могло бути окремої від російської термінології? Перші вживання цього слова, що я знайшов вже після 2СВ.

Comment: Чому Ви такі категоричні? Думаю, відтоді, відколи й сама 'роза' (див. етимологічний словник). І запозичення аж ніяк не з російської.

Comment: Хоч _роза_ і не московське слово, але _розарій_ _може_ запозичене відти.

Comment: @stegetsj, а може й ні.

Comment: Якщо те, що я пишу й виглядає категоричним, то не з моєй волі. Я хочу сказати, що якщо перші вживання слова *розарій* в укрмові з'явились вже за радянських часів, особливо після 33го, то нема сенсу посилатись на це слово як сертифікат (тнавіть частковий) українськості слова *роза* у значенні *троянда*.

Comment: @Yola, до радянських часів не було розаріїв в Україні? Чи як вони називались до цього часу? [Розарій](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9), [Розарій (квітник)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_(%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA))

Comment: @Yola, і я за зворотню логічну послідовність. Якщо роза не росіянізм, то й розарій - відповідно, а не навпаки.

Comment: Я мав на увазі слово розарій лише в значені квітник. Відповідна стаття в вікі не проливає світло на те, коли це слово з'явилось в укрмові. Щодо послідовності, то логічно припустити, що нам не дали вибирати розарій це буде чи трояндарій, тому ваше припущення за своєю формою помилкове, але це не заперечує, що *розарій* не росіянізм.

Comment: Головна моя думка полягає в тому, що нам обирати яке слово використовувати, тут після стількох років плюндрування мови, нам часом треба виступати в ролі мовотворця. І тут перевагою *троянди* і *трояндарію* є поява ще одного слова в мові, уникнення утворення омоніму.

Comment: @Yola, моє припущення, що розарій, розові, розанні тощо, як ботанічні терміни, походять з латини, як і безліч інших наукових термінів, і вплив російської тут шукати не варто. [Розові](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96)

Comment: Цікаво, що колись ми українською казали єнот і білка, а зараз як кажемо чи можемо казати? Хоча все ж цей ваш агрумент безсумнівно дає над чим подумати.

Comment: @Yola, ми тут всі спільно шукаємо відповіді. Тому Ваше зауваження щодо того, що слово розарій в значенні квітника почало використовуватись тільки за радянських часів, цікаве, якщо має під собою підгрунтя. Але в такому випадку не менш цікаво, яким словом послуговувались українські ботаніки, дендрологи до радянських часів на позначення трояндового саду. Мав же теж бути якийсь термін.

Comment: я не стверджую, що це слово з'явилось саме за радянських часів. Просто немає прикладів дорадянського вжитку, тому є така підозра.

Answer (score 4):

Навіть у вашому питанні бачимо, що і слово "роза" і "троянда" походять з грецької мови. Хоча як бачимо, в світі більші поширений перший варіант англ. "rose", нім. "Rose" та навіть рос. "роза". Та й навіть в Вікіпедія пише:

> Троя́нда (лат. **Rosa L**.), або шипши́на — рід і культурна форма
>   рослин родини розових (дикорослі — див. Шипшина), кущі до 2 метрів
>   заввишки.

Тобто саме слово "роза" походить від [біологічної номенклатури](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) цієї рослини. А тому воно так схоже із словами з інших мов.

Читаємо дальше:

> Слово **троянда — запозичення** з новогрецької мови: від τριάντα
>   «тридцять» (пелюстків), що виникло в результаті скорочення грец.
>   τριαντάφυλλο — «тридцятилистник»[3](http://sum.in.ua/s/ruzha).
>
> Назви роза, рожа та ружа (через пол. róża) походять від лат. rosa (*яке в свою чергу також походить з грецької мови*).

В СУМі є також і "[рожа](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozha)" і "[ружа](http://sum.in.ua/s/ruzha)".

І хочу підмітити, що лише біля цих двох слів стоять позначки "розм." чи "діал.", що означає що краще уникати цих слів в деяких випадках. А от коло слів "роза" та "троянда" таких позначок немає, а тому ми можемо їх вживати не боючись, що це буде помилкою.